# Centering Button In Wordpress With Different Screen Sizes (OT Button)

Tags: wordpress

Alright, I need some help centering this button! I have it working on my desktop but when I adjust the screen size it really gets messed up. Here are some screenshots to give some context. Here is the link to my website, the button is below the main slider "Orion CostPlus Strategy"

[In the page developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBAo3.png)

[Button correctly centered when full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4xMt.png)

[Button messed up when I change window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7W7Y.png)

I appreciate any help!

Comment: https://orioncostplus.com is the website I am working on.... Forgot the address.

Comment: You need to center the content of the column as well. Right now it is left-aligned inside the column (although it seems centered on larger screensizes). It looks like you're using some sort of page builder, so depending on which, you'd need to look into centering inside the column.